# how to post data using AJAX with validation using bootstrap 5?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

How can I post ajax with form validation in bootstrap 5 ?

```
 // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function () {
  'use strict'

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
    .forEach(function (form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity()) {
          event.preventDefault()
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
   
        form.classList.add('was-validated')
      }, false)
    })
})()
```

I have a big problem with this. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Any example how you post a form with data?

Comment: its doesn't matter for me. validation is working good. but I don't know; how can I add Ajax POST with bootstrap 5 standart validation

Comment: Why do you use `event.preventDefault()`? If you just want to post when the form is submitted, you can just remove it.

Comment: I want it to check and send.

Comment: The form would be checked when you submit it. You don't need to explicitly to use `form.checkValidity()`.

Comment: Can you write an example for me? fiddle

Comment: A [demo](https://jsbin.com/dicuxazugo/edit?html,output), You can try to click the submit button and found that there would be validation message for you if you don't input anything or not a right format of email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above starter code provided by [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#custom-styles) uses the [`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/checkValidity) method of JavaScript [Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Constraint_validation) to validate the form.

> The HTMLInputElement.checkValidity() method returns a boolean value
> which indicates validity of the value of the element. If the value is
> invalid, this method also fires the invalid event on the element.

You can make the ajax request if validation is successful as below,

```js
if (!form.checkValidity()) {
   event.preventDefault()
   event.stopPropagation()
}else{
   //make your ajax request here
}
```

Here is an example ajax request using JavaScript [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API and [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) API

```js
if (!form.checkValidity()) {
   event.preventDefault()
   event.stopPropagation()
}else{
  try {
     const postData = new FormData(form)
     const response = await fetch('url', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(postData)
      });
     //Response from server
     const data = await response.json();
  }catch(e){
     //handle error
     console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict'

    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    Array.prototype.slice.call(forms)
        .forEach(function (form) {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();  // event.default or form submit
                    formPost();  // call function whatever you want
                }
                form.classList.add('was-validated')
            }, false)
        })
})()

function formPost(){
    var form_data = $("form#mainform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: form_data,
        // dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#queryResulDiv').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#queryResulDiv').html("ERROR:" + xhr.responseText + " - " + thrownError);
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    })
}
```